# using jfrog cli to upload from a file on stdin?

Tags: upload, artifactory, stdin

I want to upload a file to artifactory but the contents are coming over stdin.

Imagine I have a remote private artifactory instance only accessible via an ssh jump box which only has a small disk, so I want to do the command below, where the '-' stands for "get the contents from stdin, just as tar knows that '-' means stdin.

```
$ ssh jumpbox "jfrog rt u - reponame/dir/myfile.tgz" < myfile.tgz
```

I even tried using mkfifo and getting jfrog to read the named pipe/fifo but it didn't spot the EOF

any ideas?

Comment: You should probably request this as a feature in their [tracker](https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli)